# DynamicDataDisplay multiple line graphs

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dynamic-data-display

I am using Dynamic Data Display and want to display a variable number of line graphs at runtime depending on a user selection. I can bind a single line graph to data in my viewmodel as shown below. (I am trying to strictly follow MVVM).

View

`<d3:ChartPlotter>
<d3:LineGraph DataSource="{Binding Data}"></d3:LineGraph>
</d3:ChartPlotter>`

ViewModel

```
`public ObservableDataSource<Point> Data {
        get => _data;
        set
        {
            _data = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Data");
        }
    }`
```

Should I dynamically add LineGraphs to the ChartPlotter after the user selection? I was hoping that I could bind to a list of `ObservableDataSource<Point>` where each element in the list corresponds to a LineGraph series but this does not seem possible.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.